# Laravel 5.4.* - The "" directory does not exist when running artisan

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-5

I have a fresh installation of **Ubuntu Server 14.04** in which I'm currently trying to install my **Laravel** project on.

I have moved the entire repository into the folder required, but when I run the command

```
php artisan
```

within that directory, the terminal returns an error stating

```
[InvalidArgumentException]

The "" directory does not exist.
```

Does anyone know what I can possibly do to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you run `composer install` ?

Comment: First check storage/logs/laravel.log for errors. If it is empty check \var\log\apache2\error.log

Comment: did you install laravel with laravel new? if so the project is probably a level deeper. you can check if you do `ls` in your terminal. You should see artisan listed.

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn I have already ran `composer install` with no prevail
@RavishaHesh I'm not getting any direct errors related to the situation
@Christophvh This isn't a fresh installation, I was moving the project to a different server

Comment: Try composer install and check again

Answer (score 16):

I had this same issue and it turned out that I was not cloning the `./config` directory because of a poorly defined `.gitignore`. So make sure the original project location was able to push that directory up and that it exists in the new location.

After the clone I re-ran `composer install` and it all worked.

Comment: I checked my config directory after your comment and found out it was deleted by mistake ‍♂️‍♂️ wasted an hour trying to figure out the issue ‍♂️ thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had been facing the same issue and I found that there was an empty folder in `Module Directory`. I had just deleted that `Module Directory` and again started with new `Module Directory` and it had solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, resolved it by running `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: i got the same issue even if i run `artisan config:cache` or `artisan route:cache`  ... did you solve your `artisan optimize` problem ?

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i run composer install and it through below error

```
Problem 1
    - lcobucci/jwt is locked to version 4.1.4 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

then I run

```
composer update
```

and it worked like a charm.