# The "" directory does not exist - php artisan into DO droplet created by forge

Tags: laravel, digital-ocean, forge

I created a droplet with Laravel Forge onto DigitalOcean.
Then I created a website, which I connected to a git repository.
When connecting with ssh forge@...... and type php artisan into the project directory, it shows me a error message:

The "" directory does not exist

How can I solve it?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Possibly duplicated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004461/laravel-5-4-the-directory-does-not-exist-when-running-artisan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.4.\* - The "" directory does not exist when running artisan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004461/laravel-5-4-the-directory-does-not-exist-when-running-artisan)